# UIScrollView crop to take Device scale and zoom scale into effect?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a simple crop feature that takes into effect device screen-density and zoom-scale

I basically modeled it after the code in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hz9pMw4Y2Lk

```
func cropImage(sender:AnyObject!) { //triggered by a button

    let myScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    var height = self.scrollView.bounds.height
    var width = self.scrollView.bounds.width

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), true, myScale)
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset

    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)
    scrollView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //i would like to check here if target image is >300x300px
    if image.size.width > 300 && image.size.height > 300{

        println("image correct")
        println(image.size)

    } else {

        println("nope")
        println(image.size)
    }
}
```

So far I will always end up having an image that is bounds.height/width -which means that on a 320 device incl. a 8xp leading/trailing gap, the user might never be able to create a "correct image".

I understand why it happens, but I do not understand where I should be multiplying with device-scale factor and/or zoom-factor of the UIScrollView.

For example having a camera picture imported at ScrollView zoom-scale 0.0 - i want to keep it at ~8MP'ish.